# Extract 2 digit from a BigInt of 8 digit in Hive

Tags: date, hive, bigint

In my hive table I need to extract from column DATE(stored as bigint), 2 digits(month) in center.

For Example:

`20220120` -> `01`

`20211201` -> `12`

Is it possible to do directly without casting column `DATE` to string?

Thanks

Comment: You want to do this in Hive?

Answer (score 0):

`substr` should work.

```
select substr( 20220101,4,2)
```

[image]